# Weblogic Log4j Loggging Server Logging Bridge throws ClassCastException when starting up

Tags: java, oracle, log4j, weblogic

With Weblogic 11g I have done the following:

1  Created log4j.xml file where I created a new appender:

> ```
>    <appender name="WEBLOGIC" class="weblogic.logging.log4j.ServerLoggingAppender">
>   <param name="Threshold" value="ERROR"/>
>    </appender>
>    
>    <root>
>      <priority value="WARN"/>
>      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
>      <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
>      <appender-ref ref="WEBLOGIC"/>
>    </root>
> ```

2  Updated the ${DOMAIN_HOME}/bin/setDomainEnv.sh script with these changes:

> ```
> LOG4J_CONFIG_FILE="${DOMAIN_HOME}/config/log4j.xml"
> if [ "${LOG4J_CONFIG_FILE}" != "" ] ; then
>   JAVA_PROPERTIES="${JAVA_PROPERTIES} Dlog4j.configuration=file:${LOG4J_CONFIG_FILE}"
>   export JAVA_PROPERTIES
> fi
>
> JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} ${JAVA_PROPERTIES} -Dweblogic.log.Log4jLoggingEnabled=true -Dwlw.iterativeDev=${iterativeDevFlag} -Dwlw.testConsole=${testConsoleFlag} -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole=${logErrorsToConsoleFlag}"
> ```

3  Copied the log4j jars to the domain/lib

> cp ./wlserver_10.3/server/lib/wllog4j.jar user_projects/domains/my_domain/lib/
>
> cp ./wlserver_10.3/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.8.jar user_projects/domains/my_domain/lib/

4  Starts the AdminServer, but I get this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
> weblogic.logging.log4j.ServerLoggingAppender cannot be cast to
> org.apache.log4j.Appender

Comment: Do you need to include the `log4j-1.2.8.jar`? If Weblogic has its own `Appender` then it should already contain the log4j classes and there might be a conflict.

Comment: If I remove the log4j-1.2.8.jar from $DOMAIN_HOME/lib I get this:


`<Nov 16, 2012 8:28:49 AM MST> <Error> <Log Management> <BEA-170022> <Log4j failed to initialize for AdminServer. The default JDK Logging implementation will be used.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/spi/LoggerFactory
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)`

Answer (score 0):

Keep step 1 and remove changes done in other steps.

Now copy the log4j.xml to $DOMAIN_HOME/lib folder. This will keep your log4j.xml in the server's classpath and the server will use this log4j.xml as its log4j configuration. No additional changes are required.

Comment: If I remove the log4j-1.2.8.jar from $DOMAIN_HOME/lib I get this:

`<Nov 16, 2012 8:28:49 AM MST> <Error> <Log Management> <BEA-170022> <Log4j failed to initialize for AdminServer. The default JDK Logging implementation will be used.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/spi/LoggerFactory
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)`

Comment: I put it in the $DOMAIN_HOME/lib I didn't get that exception but I did get this one:

`log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.gdc4s.ei.log4jexample.app.lifecycle.MyListener).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.`

Answer (score 0):

In `setDomainEnv.xml` file, please add the set `log4j.xml` location as below:

```
set LOG4J_CONFIG_FILE=C:\bea\user_projects\domains\dev\lib\log4j.xml

if NOT "%LOG4J_CONFIG_FILE%"=="" (
    set JAVA_PROPERTIES=%JAVA_PROPERTIES% -Dlog4j.configuration=file:%LOG4J_CONFIG_FILE%
)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have to see is if despite the warning that you get, if the ServerLogging is effectively not working on your appliction on your domain.
Probably not even there since you are only copying the log4j to the domain/lib folder but not the wllog4j.jar. 
So your setup looks like is doomed not to work in any case.

To me, It looks to me that you are undergoing Class Loader Vodoo Messup.

(1) You set a global log4j properties file for the entire app server.

(2) it looks like weblogic console app is itself a ear and it bundles its own LOG4J implementation library, which you are copying into your domain.

When the console app runs, it must for sure make use of Log4j and the class loader loading the Log4j Appender definition is most likely a level lower than the class loader that knows about the ServerLoggin bridge adapter.
I am beting its for reason like this that weblogic is geting rid of LOG4j in future gnerations of the product. 
They have too many class loader issues - JUL logging you have the APP class loader behind the core classes - such as Handlers/Adapters.

Anyway.

(3) When weblogic runs, namley when it bootstraps the console it probably runs some sort class loader that gives a level of isolation to the libs bundled in the applicaiton and it sees:
Oh! How nice, LOG4j is here, leets initialize it.

Second, LOG4j bootstraps and hits head on your log4j.properties where you put the server logging appender in there - cross cutingly for everybody (including the weblogic application console).
He goes hunting for this library and where does it find it?

One of them, the wllog4j.jar he finds somewhere in the weblogic generic container libraries. While the base core classes of Log4j he finds a level lower in the domain configuration or in the EAR configuraiton of the console applicaiton. 
This is not good.

Try the following:
(a) go into the weblogic console app, go to the Meta Inf folder and re-write the weblogi-application.xml

It will have a prefer applicaiton packages that looks like this:
     
        org.apache.log4j.*</package-name-->  <---- here I've commented this line.

If you comment the above line, the application class loader will search for log4j libraries in the highest parent that knows about these classes.
So if you put at the same level where your ServerLogger is found you should be fine.

(b) Pug the log4j implementation library at the same level where the wllog4j.jar will be found.

Check if you still get the casting exceptions.

Be very careful when you make server wide cross cuting configurations.

Good luck.